# WHY can I not found "TLSv1_3_client_method()" when programming with openssl?

Tags: sockets, openssl

I'm currently writing a client program on Linux Ubuntu 16.04. I want to use OpenSSL to secure communication. But I get this error when I use gcc to complie my source code:

**$gcc -o client1 client.c -lssl -lcrypto**

**"undefined reference to "TLSv1_3_client method"**

[image]

The version of my OpenSSL is **1.1.1d**:

[image]

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `TLSv1_3_client_method`. And even the older `TLSv1_2_client_method` and similar are [documented as deprecated](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSLv23_client_method.html). Instead you should use `TLS_client_method` which will also support TLS 1.3. If you want to restrict support to only TLS 1.3 you need to use [SSL_CTX_set_options](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CTX_set_options.html) and similar with `SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_2`, `SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_1`, ...

Comment: Your anwser give me a clear clue to solve my problem.From the manual page,I found it more convenient to restrict support to only TLS1.3 by using the method `SSL_CTX_set_max_proto_version()` and similar.